# setTimeout and callback - not allowing Browser to render refreshed DOM elements

Tags: javascript, callback, settimeout

I have a function that updates some DOM elements and then calls a callback using a setTimeout as follows (if one is provided - otherwise a dummy function is called):

```
        function updateprogressbar(id,val,label,callback) {
            var time = 0;
            if (typeof callback === "function") {
                var func = callback;
            } else {
                var func = function () {};
            }
            $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
                value: val
            });
            $( "#progress-label"+id ).html("Overall Progress: "+label);
            setTimeout(func(),time);
        }
```

Called with this for loop:

```
        for(var i=0;i<emails.length;i++) {
            var howmuchdone = Math.ceil(totalchecked*100/totaltocheck);
            updateprogressbar(1,howmuchdone,howmuchdone+"%",function () {                   
                $("#EMAIL_ALL").val($("#EMAIL_ALL").val()+","+getmeadescriptor($.trim(emails[i])));
            });
            totalchecked = totalchecked + 1;
        }
```

It is executing it's callback correctly, but my purpose in using the setTimeout was to ensure that the browser rendered the updated DOM elements. For reasons I can't figure out, the DOM elements aren't being updated.

(updateprogressbar is being called within a for loop, and the callback passed to it is an anonymous function that does some straightforward processing - although I don't think that's relevant to this problem.)

Any ideas as to why I'm not getting any browser rendering on the updateprogressbar call?

Thanks!

So, following @vinhHT's comment, I'll try this:

```
                var testfunction = function (value) {
                    $("#EMAIL_ALL").val($("#EMAIL_ALL").val()+","+value;
                }

                for(var i=0;i<emails.length;i++) {
                    var howmuchdone = Math.ceil(totalchecked*100/totaltocheck);
                    updateprogressbar(1,howmuchdone,howmuchdone+"%",testfunction(getmeadescriptor($.trim(emails[i]))));
                    totalchecked = totalchecked + 1;
                }
```

Comment: Your code suggests that `func()` is an empty function. Place your DOM manipulation code within that function for it to work. Also, as what others have pointed out, a duration of 0 is too short for setTimeout.

Comment: You have to allow the current thread of execution to finish and return the event loop for a repaint to happen this way.  Just calling `setTimeout()` and pointing it at a dummy function, even if you properly called the `setTimeout()` doesn't help anything.

Comment: you're missing a ")" at the last of: $("#EMAIL_ALL").val($("#EMAIL_ALL").val() + "," + getmeadescriptor($.trim(emails[i])));

Comment: Thanks - sorry - bad copy/paste! Fixed above on edit!

Comment: ok, i think i see the problem, you declare your func inside the if-else block and call it outer,

Comment: Ah-ha! I see - so I'll declare it with a name (rather than keep it as an anonymous) before the loop and call if by name as the callback. Will try that. Thanks!

Comment: You can try my latest edited answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @VinhNT- unfortunately declaring the function outside of the for loop and then providing it as a parameter for the callback doesn't work. In fact when I thought about it further, the use of an anonymous function should mean that is essentially redeclared and within required scope anyway for the callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Now, that you've disclosed the `for` loop code, we can see that to let each cycle of your loop do a repaint before the next cycle executes, you need to start each next iteration of the loop with a `setTimeout()`.  That allows the code to return to the event loop between loop executions.  You can do that like this:

```
// utility function to iterate a loop, but have a short `setTimeout()` 
// pause between each loop iteration
// assumes mainFn is a synchronous operation
// doneFn is optional and, if present, will be called when all iterations are done
function iterateWithRepaint(start, num, incr, mainFn, doneFn){
    var end = start + num;
    function next() {
        if (start < end) {
            mainFn(start);
            start += incr;
            setTimeout(next, 20);
        } else {
            if (typeof doneFn === "function") {
                doneFn();
            }
        }
    }
    next();
}

// got rid of callback in here since it was not helpful
// and added loop index as an argument
function updateprogressbar(id, val, label, i) {
    var time = 0;
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
        value: val
    });
    $("#EMAIL_ALL").val($("#EMAIL_ALL").val()+","+getmeadescriptor($.trim(emails[i])));
    $( "#progress-label"+id ).html("Overall Progress: "+label);
}    

// call your function with a timer delay between each iteration
iterateWithRepaint(0, emails.length, 1, function(i) {
    var howmuchdone = Math.ceil(totalchecked*100/totaltocheck);
    updateprogressbar(1,howmuchdone,howmuchdone+"%", i);
    totalchecked = totalchecked + 1;
});
```

There are some other ways to trigger a reflow and sometimes a repaint by requesting certain CSS properties that can only be accurately reported after a full relayout so the browser forces a relayout, but this method has proved to be an elusive and moving target because browsers keep trying to optimize away what they consider unnecessary repaints in the interest of improved performance.  So, I choose not to rely on those techniques.

---

Prior Answer before loop code disclosed:

Your `setTimeout()` is improperly declared, but there is more to your problem than that.

A `setTimeout()`, even if properly declared, does not by itself allow your page to referesh.  All that does is schedule some code to run in the future.  Instead, you have to stop running code now and put the future code INTO the `setTimeout` callback.  Only that lets the current thread return to the event loop and then gives the screen a chance to repaint.

FYI, your `setTimeout()` should be like this:

```
setTimeout(func,time);
```

But changing that in the code you show won't fix anything because `func()` as you show it doesn't actually do anything and therefore won't actually allow a repaint.  If ALL your future code was inside of `func()` AND, there was no more code in your current thread of execution to run after the call to `setTimeout()`, then it would likely allow a repaint.

If you show us the rest of your code that's delaying the repaint, then we can probably help you more specifically.  The code you show doesn't delay a repaint by itself.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00. All of my future code is within the callback passed to the updateprogressbar function. var func is set to the callback and then called within the setTimeout, so I think this should work? If no callback is provided, then I fully appreciate that I wont see any repaint.

Comment: @ChrisJones - You say in your question that "updateprogressbar is being called within a for loop".  The duration of that `for` loop will block repaints until the `for` loop is done, no matter what's in a properly declared `setTimeout()` callback.   If you want help keeping the `for` loop from blocking repaints, we need to see more code, including the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 - please see edit above which shows the calling for loop. I may be missing something here - all I am trying to achieve is to reliably repaint at the end of every for loop interation - any other suggestions would be most appreciated as I've been struggling with this for a while!

Comment: @ChrisJones - I added a new answer that now takes into account your loop.  You need to next iteration of the loop to actually be executed by a `setTimeout()`.  I've provided a utility function to do that restructured your code to be called by that.  Since I can't run this code, I'm not sure it's perfectly error free, but you should be able to see the general idea and fix any syntax or logic errors that show up.

Comment: Thanks again @jfriend00 - I understand and have learnt something - really appreciate your time in putting this together  - I'll test and revert!

Comment: Nice answer, @jfriend00 :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove () in your setTimeout

```
As setTimeout(func,time);
```

Edit after jfriend00's comment:

1. declare the function correctly as:

   var func = function() {
     //business goes here
   }
2. Correct the call to above callback in the code as

   setTimeout(func, time);

3 edit as question has been edited: declare func outside the if-else block, correct the setTimeout call

```
function updateprogressbar(id, val, label, callback) {
    var time = 0;
    var func;
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        func = callback;
    } else {
        func = function() {};
    }
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value: val
    });
    $("#progress-label" + id).html("Overall Progress: " + label);
    setTimeout(func, time);
}
```

Comment: Their `setTimeout()` was wrong, but I don't see how, in the code they show, this actually solves their problem since `func()` doesn't actually do anything so wouldn't be delaying a repaint.

Comment: func can be declare some where else, like var func = function() { /// logic code };

Comment: The point is that your answer does not fix the problem because the problem you're talking about is an incorrect piece of code, but per the code they show that problem does not delay a repaint.  So, as they say "These are not the droids you're looking for".

Comment: He said in the question: "I have a function that updates some DOM elements and then calls a callback" and I understand that he has a callback function somewhere

Comment: Yes, there is an anonymous function passed in via the callback param.

Comment: The OP says that "updateprogressbar is being called within a for loop".  That means that `for` loop will block repaint processing no matter what is in the `setTimeout()`.  The OP needs to show us more of the code, including the `for` loop.